# Ionic - set style to Checkbox-Text when checked

Tags: css, checkbox, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a first ToDo-App for my own.

I want to use ionic, because we will need it later at work (so I can make some experiences).

Now - I have my app with simple to-do tasks, which is a list of checkboxes, implemented as

```
<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="task in activeProject.tasks"
              ng-model="task.checked"
              ng-change="toggleItemDisplay(task)">
    {{ task.title }}
</ion-checkbox>
```

I can write something into the console with this "toggleItemDisplay"-Function, which is implemented in the controller

```
//Toggle the text-display on checkbox
$scope.toggleItemDisplay = function(task) {
    if(task.checked == true) {
        console.log(task.title);
    } else {
        console.log('not checked!');
    }
}
```

I would like the text which is displayed next to the checkbox (-> it's the task.title) to get the style "text-decoration: line-through" when the checkbox is checked.

How can I add the style-Attribut? It must be so simple but I just can't find the right solution..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `ng-class` for a conditional CSS class

```js
angular.module('example', ['ionic'])
.controller('c', ['$scope', function($scope) {

// Mock of your tasks
$scope.tasks = [
   { title : "test 1", checked : false },
   { title : "test 2", checked : true },
];

$scope.toggleItemDisplay = function(task) {
    if(task.checked == true) {
        console.log(task.title);
    } else {
        console.log('not checked!');
    }
}
}]);
```

```css
.task-done {
  text-decoration:  line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.13/js/angular/angular.min.js "></script>
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.13/js/ionic.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.13/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<div ng-app="example">
  <div ng-controller="c">

    <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="task in tasks"
                  ng-model="task.checked"
                  ng-change="toggleItemDisplay(task)"
                  ng-class="{'task-done': task.checked}">
                  {{ task.title }}
    </ion-checkbox>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I knew it must be quite simple but didn't catch the "ng-class" element. Saved my day!